# Post form data of type datetime-local to sql table datetime field

Tags: mysql, forms, datetime, sqldatatypes

I want to ask what does the data look like when I submit a form with an `input` field with `datetime-local` as its `type` (and also what about just `date` or `time`)?

In particular, the form data will be submitted to a sql database table under a column with `DATETIME` as its data type.

Will there be any preprocessing I need to do before I insert the record, or what's the way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Silly question haha

It was totally viable!


For anyone actually wondering...


You can go to this w3Schools page to play with the example i.e. by setting the `type` field for one of the input to `datetime-local` and hit submit. It will come back with the data you submitted, which should look something like this:
`2069-04-20T04:20`


Then when you post this to the `sql` database table, it will look something below under the relative column:
`2069-04-20 04:20:00`